# VMware player: How to change position of menu bar in full screen?

Tags: vmware-player

I'm running Ubuntu in VMware Player in fullscreen mode.

When an application window is expanded, its menu is shown at very top of the screen. When I move mouse cusror to select something in the application menu, Player's menu bar appears over application menu and I cannot use the application menu.

Is there any way to move the Player menu bar to the bottom of the screen?

Comment: I'd love an answer on this, too...